# golang variable setting

Tags: go

I need to set a variable at the beginning of my package that will later on be populated with parseFiles() but im not sure how to set the variable considering its not a string or int or anything generic like that. How would i set the variable without having to add some arbitrary name in there just to set it?

```go
var templatefiles = template.New("foo") // Im having to do New("foo") just to set the variable

// Later on adding files to original variable
templatefiles.New("template name").Parse("Template text here")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to replace `= template.New("foo")` with the type returned. In this case:

```
var templatefiles *template.Template // the return type of html/template.New()
```

templatefiles is now a global variable that contains a nil pointer to a type `template.Template`.

Comment: That worked thanks!!! What if later on i want to clear out the variable? Basically empty out the templates that are in the var templatefiles?

Comment: As with any pointer, you set it to nil. `templatefiles = nil`

Comment: Im sorry i was wrong it did not work. this is the error i get. http://play.golang.org/p/a0irFLNgpo

Comment: You tried to use `templates` before creating one. http://play.golang.org/p/RitlvGxTrG

Comment: haha yes you are right. but my issue just adds a bit more complication and i was wondering your thoughts on how to make it work using your previous playground. http://play.golang.org/p/rkxa3XUNXi

Comment: Thats what i figured. Thanks so much for your help. Shoot me an email using the one on my profile page. Would love to chat on your expertise on go language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17905/discussion-between-brian-voelker-and-stephen-weinberg)